# saving questdb database on an external disk

Tags: questdb

I don't have enough space on my computer so I am trying to create a questdb on an external hard drive. Is there a way I can do this?

I am looking at the [documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/configuration/) and going through `~/.questdb/conf` directory but can't seem to find a good way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One option is that you can use a directory on the external hard drive as the database root directory. As a slightly more complicated option, you can detach some of your partitions, move them to the external disk and create a symlink:

- https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/alter-table-attach-partition/#symbolic-link

One more thing to mention is that you can create the whole table on the external disk (this feature is not yet released, but should be shipped soon in v7.0.1):

- https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/create-table/#table-target-volume